# Where to locate my private key to SSH?

Tags: cryptography, ssh, key-generation

In my understanding, to ssh login to my server, I need a private key:

[image]

However, the key I get when generating seems to be a public key:
[image]

Do you know where to locate my private key?

[Manually generating your SSH key in Windows](https://docs.joyent.com/public-cloud/getting-started/ssh-keys/generating-an-ssh-key-manually/manually-generating-your-ssh-key-in-windows#git-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `Enter file...` you have chosen an arbitrary filename `public_key_ooker`. That's why the privake key has been saved to `public_key_ooker` and public key to `public_key_ooker.pub`. The name alone doesn't make the private key a public key, but gets you confused.

But you don't necessarily need a key, if you are using password authentication. If you'd rather use public key authentication, which is actually a good idea, the server needs to be aware of your public key: you need to save the line to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.